# Calling a function is JQuery after all ajax calls(number of ajax calls are dynamic) have received responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

HTML:-

Result

Javascript:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#result").html("function started here");
var requests = Array();
requests.push($.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA'));
requests.push($.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=EGL, Bangalore'));
var defer = $.when.apply($, requests);
  console.log(defer);
defer.done(function(){
$("#result").html("Completed");
    // This is executed only after every ajax request has been completed
    $.each(arguments, function(index, responseData){

     // alert(index);
     $("#result").html(responseData);
        // "responseData" will contain an array of response information for each specific request
    });

});
  });
```

The above snippet works only when all ajax calls returns "success" response. Is there any way where i can know if all ajax calls gets response,may it be "success" / "failure" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can you ajaxStart,ajaxStop,ajaxError,ajaxSuccess.

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            //when ajax start
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
           //when ajax stop
        }).ajaxError(function () {
            //when ajax error
        }).ajaxSuccess(function () {
        // when ajax success
    });
```

This will trigger for every ajax call.

Comment: Thanks venkat :-) it helped.

Comment: is there any way to know which ajax calls failed and which ajax are success?

Comment: no ..(ajaxStart,ajaxStop,ajaxError,ajaxSuccess.)These function fire up globally .

There is one way, trace with retrun value .

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit venkat.Its not clear to me.How to trace with return value.

Comment: .ajaxSuccess(function (data) {
       if(data.d == "something")
    });

Comment: to be precise i want to print the url which gave a failure response inside ajaxError and url which gave a success response inside ajaxSuccess

Comment: ajaxStop doesn't seem to be working for dynamic ajax calls ,as it will wait only for OUTSTANDING ajax request.And it wont have any idea on the dynamic ajax that may be fired later.